# StackExchange is not defined - All Browsers

Tags: support

I'm currently not able to use Stackoverflow, AskUbuntu and I suppose many other websites using the same engine as the CSS seems to not appear. I've tried clearing cookies, I'm running on Ubuntu and the issue is happening both in Mozilla and in Chrome. Screen looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qurpi.png . I've seen other posts with this problem, but none of them resolved my issue. Here's console  code that I get:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=fa3753e2f985
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=870bf30df33b
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined (index):27
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined (index):36
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined (index):215
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined (index):306
Uncaught ReferenceError: StackExchange is not defined (index):3185
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some sort? Where are you located? (the CDNs have regional endpoints.)

Comment: I'm not behind any proxy as far as I've checked in Ubuntu's networking   settings. Nor did I download any proxy software. I'm located in Romania

Comment: Hmm, it seems strange that *two* CDNs would be refusing the connection actively, independently from each other. (Quantcast and Stack Exchange's CDN have nothing to do with each other as far I know). That's why I'm thinking it *might* be a proxy, or something else on your machine - maybe some overreaching security software? Not sure

Comment: Are you in a corperate network?

Comment: I'm not in a corporate network. I'm pretty sure I'm not using any proxy. Is there any way I could be aside from browser extension or through a modification in the Network page of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what the issue was, but now all of these work seamlessly. I didn't do anything but shut down my PC for a day, which should have no effect as I've rebooted it when the problem persisted. Thank you for the help provided, regardless.